# Creating Relationships between SAS variables

Tags: sas

I am creating a SAS program which allows the user to input the date they want to investigate (as a global variable). I want to create a second variable which is three months before the user created variable.

```
%let var1 = [user manually writes the variable in the code] 
%let var2 = [3 months before var1]
```

I tried

```
var2 = intnx('month', input(put(&var1.,8.),yymmdd8.),-3)
```

which does not work.

Comment: You seem to be mixing macro variables and actual dataset variables in your code.  You will need to tell the users exactly what format they should use to enter dates into the first macro variable that will be compatible with the method you use to generate the second macro variable. Remember that SAS macro variables are just text strings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to use and create macro variables that have date strings in the format of YYYYMMDD then you could do that using %SYSFUNC().

```
%let date1=20170213 ;
%let date2=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&date1,yymmdd8)),-3),yymmddn8);
%put &=date1 &=date2;


DATE1=20170213 DATE2=20161101
```